# Is there a way I can tell if someone is programatically accessing my website with selenium if they are doing it at a low rate and with no clicks?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to learn more about how selenium works. And to specifically answer the question: is it possible to know if someone is programatically accessing my website at a low rate using selenium webdriver?

edit: this is quite related, but it is dated  [Selenium Webdriver is detectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938916/selenium-webdriver-is-detectable)

Also, there is a recent specification for webdrivers that includes a webdriver-active flag http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-webdriver-active-flag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver is detectable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938916/selenium-webdriver-is-detectable)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't reliably determine if a human or a selenium process is interacting with your system. All your server sees are http requests.