# Selenium: How to Disable webdriver="true" in Firefox?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm using Selenium with Java (via Firefox) to perform some automation tasks. I noticed Selenium adds `webdriver="true"` to HTML. This means Selenium is easily detectable.

My question is how can I disable this?

I know there is a similar question on SO here: [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) but this question is about Chrome and I am using Firefox. Further, the discussion revolves around how companies detect automation. I know companies can detect automation in various ways but I simply want to know one thing - how to disable the webdriver="true"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While it's not an answer I wanted to point out some information that may help to solve/understand problem better.

Extract taken from one of the answers on this question:

[Selenium Webdriver is detectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938916/selenium-webdriver-is-detectable)

User under a nick JimEvans has written:

"The W3C draft spec states in Appendix E that drivers should provide a mechanism for fingerprinting that a browser is being driven by WebDriver. At the moment, no implementations comply with this section of the spec. The Firefox driver currently comes closest, adding an attribute to the html tag. Future versions and drivers of other browsers will likely implement methods of detection in line with the specification."